# Make Spring Service Classes Final?

Tags: java, spring

Can I make the spring service classes final? Is there any harm doing that? Nobody is going to extend the class. Is there any issue?

```
public final class MyService {
   // Depedencies go here.
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Don't make them `final`. If you use any AOP (including transaction support) on concrete classes, spring will use CGLIB to dynamically extend your class in order to make a proxy. And the requirement for CGLIB to work is to have your classes non-`final`. Otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Good answer. So DAO classes can be `final`? They are not usually transactional.

Comment: Well, then _can_, but be careful with that as well. You might at some point add some AOP to them as well.

Comment: It's a flaw of those tools to not be able to instrument `final` classes, which are a must for proper OO design (see, for instance, the "Practical API Design" book - or even the GoF book). There *are* ways to instrument final classes; tools like CGLIB are obsolete.

Comment: @Rogerio the question is about spring, and this is the way to do it in spring, good or bad. So I don't agree with you (and the downvote). spring uses CGLIB. When you say there are ways, please list these ways. I can only think of aspectj perhaps. Is it this what you mean?

Comment: @Bozho: Yes, and Spring also uses AspectJ, which can instrument final classes. At the low level, there are two approaches for runtime bytecode modification that can be used for this sort of thing: java.lang.instrument, and a custom classloader. The first one has the ability of *redefining* classes, in addition to load-time modification. IMO, frameworks like Spring should dump old and limited tools such as CGLIB, Javaassist, etc. and take advantage of java.lang.instrument + ASM.

Comment: @Rogerio true, but my opinion is that instrumentation and weaving are not exactly pure-OOP :) Compared to not supporting final, I can't decide which is the lesser evil.

Comment: @Bozho: Whether instrumentation is OOP or not is irrelevant here, as they would be used to implement a tool or framework used by client code. Besides, so what? Is only OOP valid? What about functional programming in Scala, static methods, etc.? About `final`, not supporting it is not an option! That would be equivalent to not supporting `private`, for example; any OO language must support both overridable and non-overridable classes & methods, as they are both essential in OO design. Therefore, libraries/tools/frameworks for those languages must support it too.

Answer (score 13):

Spring will create a JDK dynamic proxy rather than a CGLIB proxy if the following are true:

1. aop:config has proxy-target-classes set to false
2. Any other namespace configurations (e.g. tx:transaction-management) also have proxy-target-classes set to false
3. Your class implements an interface

If all three are true, then you can declare the class final.  (You can even make the class package-private and the constructor private if you like, Spring will be able to instantiate it).

Otherwise, Spring will create a CGLIB proxy.  You can still declare the class final (assuming it is not decorated with @Repository and you do not have a PersistenceExceptionPostBeanProcessor declared) if there are no public methods in the bean.  Once you have a single public method, you cannot declare the class final with CBLIB proxying.  (Note:  you must have at least a package-private, no-argument constructor when proxying via CGLIB).

When is the above useful?  Say you have a service interface (all services should generally have interfaces) with an implementation bean that is package private.  The service is using JDK dynamic proxying.  So, it can be final and non-visible outside the package, leaking fewer implementation details.  Say the service needs a data access object.  If no other service uses this DAO, why make it or any of its methods public?  If all the methods on the DAO are package-private, the service implementation can still wire the DAO in and use its methods.  From outside the package, callers only see the interface (a good thing) and any types that are used in the interface signature.

Finally (no pun intended), make a class final whenever you can.  Concrete inheritance is both often confusing and abused (see [fragile base problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragile_base_class)).  Final classes also allow some compiler optimizations.