# java - Autowiring Repository in class that is instantiated in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

So I have an API client type class right now, which I am trying to connect to my repository so that I can store data in the MySQL database.

The problem I'm having is that the API client class instantiates a new object of itself, so the Autowiring doesn't work correctly. I've looked around for a workaround for this problem, and I've seen a couple options, but I'm confused on how to apply them to my problem.

For reference, here are parts of some of the relevant files:

GeniusApiClient.java:

```
@Component
public final class GeniusApiClient {
    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    @Autowired
    private ArtistDao artistDao;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GeniusApiClient geniusApiClient = new GeniusApiClient();
        String artistId = (geniusApiClient.getArtistId("Ugly Duckling"));

        ArrayList<String> artistSongIds = geniusApiClient.getArtistSongIds(artistId);
        System.out.println(geniusApiClient.getAllSongAnnotations(artistSongIds, artistId));
    }

    public String getAllSongAnnotations(ArrayList<String> songIds, String artistId) {
        Artist artist = new Artist("test name for now", "string123", "223");
        artistDao.save(artist);
        return "finished";
    }

}
```

ArtistDao.java:

```
@Transactional
public interface ArtistDao extends CrudRepository<Artist, Long> {
    public Artist findByGeniusId(String geniusId);
}
```

ArtistController.java:

```
@Controller
public class ArtistController {
    @Autowired
    private ArtistDao artistDao;

    /**
     * GET /create  --> Create a new artist and save it in the database.
     */
    @RequestMapping("/create")
    @ResponseBody
    public String create(String name, String annotations, String genius_id) {
        String userId = "";
        try {
            genius_id = genius_id.replaceAll("/$", "");
            Artist artist = new Artist(name, annotations, genius_id);
            artistDao.save(artist);
            userId = String.valueOf(artist.getId());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return "Error creating the artist: " + ex.toString();
        }
        return "User succesfully created with id = " + userId;
    }

   /**
     * GET /get-by-email  --> Return the id for the user having the passed
     * email.
     */
    @RequestMapping("/get")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getByEmail(String genius_id) {
        String artistId = "";
        try {
            Artist artist = artistDao.findByGeniusId(genius_id);
            artistId = String.valueOf(artist.getId());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return "User not found";
        }
        return "The user id is: " + artistId;
    }

}
```

The problem is that in GeniusApiClient.java in the getAllSongAnnotations method, I have a null pointer exception when I try and access the artistDao. I understand that my instantiation of this class is what is messing up the Autowiring, but I'm curious on what the best way to go about fixing this might be.

I considered making all of my methods in the class static so that I wouldn't have to instantiate a new method, but I don't think this would work very well. Any suggestions?

Thanks

EDIT:

Removed some irrelevant code for clarity.

EDIT2:

Added ArtistController.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to autowire/inject an object, that object must be a Spring bean.

Here you can't autowire `ArtistDao` because it's not a bean. There are several annotation options to make it bean but the one suits in this case is `@Repository` annotation. It's just a specialized version of `@Component` which you used in `GeniusApiClient` class.

So,

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ArtistDao extends CrudRepository<Artist, Long> {
    public Artist findByGeniusId(String geniusId);
}
```

should work.

I'd suggest you to read: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html

If reading reference documentation sounds scary to you, you can also take a look at **Core Spring** part of [Spring in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/spring-in-action-fourth-edition).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried adding the @Repository annotation, but to no avail. I suppose I should also have mentioned that I was actually able to successfully Autowire the ArtistDao class into a different one of my files: A Spring Controller, so I'm thinking that the problem might be elsewhere. I'll edit my post to include the class where I successfully autowired ArtistDao.

Comment: oh, now I see that you are creating a new instance of `GeniusApiClient`, and access `ArtistDao` from this instance, so Spring does not now about the instance you created and can't autowire `ArtistDao`. you should autowire `GeniusApiClient` instead creating a new instance, that will solve your problem.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! It seems I have a lot of gaps in my knowledge of how Spring works :P

Comment: try to create some time to read documentation or the book I've mentioned...good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Don't make GeniusApiClient.class final. Spring will use CGLIB to dynamically extend your class in order to make a proxy. And the requirement for CGLIB to work is to have your classes non-final.

More on this here: [Make Spring Service Classes Final?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657432/make-spring-service-classes-final)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I changed it to not be final, but unfortunately, I'm still getting artistDao to be null.

Comment: can you please share your configuration class or xml?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have a configuration class or xml. I'm not sure if Spring Boot differs from Spring MVC in that way, but the only configuration files that I've dealt with have been an `application.properties` file.

Comment: I think I got your problem. You are creating the object yourself by calling the constructor inside your main method. To be able to autowire artistDao, you need GeniusApiClient object spring managed. You need to create ApplicationContext using any xml or java config and then initialize the GeniusApiClient  object from the ApplicationContext .

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do in your catch block is not clear to me,you have to correct that and replace it with desired action to be taken on any exception occurrence.

Comment: I edited my post to remove some of irrelevant code in that method. My question has to do with why `artistDao` is null.