# Java Autowired issue

Tags: java, spring, containers, autowired

I'm struggling with `@Autowired` annotation issue. I have this code as an example but in my testing class Java says that my Autowired field is `null`. The test passes when I use `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`  but doesn't work with `@Autowired`. When I add annotation `@SpringBootTest` above my test class then `@Autowired` field then IntelliJ says "Could not autowire. No beans of 'Library' type found". I included in my root project this particular module.

```
@Repository
public class LibraryDbController {

    public void saveData(){
        System.out.println("Saving data to the database.");
    }

    public void loadData(){
        System.out.println("Loading data from the database.");
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class Library {

    private final List<String> books = new ArrayList<>();
    private LibraryDbController libraryDbController;

    public Library(LibraryDbController libraryDbController) {
        this.libraryDbController = libraryDbController;
    }

    public void saveToDb(){
        libraryDbController.saveData();
    }

    public void loadFromDb(){
        libraryDbController.loadData();
    }

}
```

```
@SpringBootTest
public class LibraryTestSuite {

    @Autowired
    private Library library; //  <--- says "Could not autowire. No beans of 'Library' type found"

    @Test
    void testLoadFromDb(){
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.spring");
        Library test = context.getBean(Library.class);

        test.loadFromDb();
    }

    @Test
    void testSaveToDb(){
        library.saveToDb();
    }

}
```

The error:

> Cannot invoke "com.spring.library.Library.saveToDb()" because "this.library" is null
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.spring.library.Library.saveToDb()" because "this.library" is null

I did not notice that when I add annotation @SpringBootTest above may tests class then all tests fail and the error occurs:

> Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

Comment: Remove `final` modificator from `LibraryDbController`

Comment: Please include the packages in your code and please add the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class as well. If you don't have that already, then that is your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your test class with `@SpringBootTest` or `@SpringJUnitConfig`

Comment: Thanks you're right, but when I add @SpringBootTest then Autowired variable is underlined and says "Could not autowired. No beans of 'Library' type found"

Comment: Have you got your application to start? With a main class with a @SpringBootApplication annotation?

Comment: @JUMBO Always inject components through constructor

Answer (score 0):

Remove `final` keyword before `LibraryDbController` declaration.

[Make Spring Service Classes Final?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657432/make-spring-service-classes-final)

Comment: Removing `final` won't solve a thing in thise case. That only applies when **class** based proxies are used, which isn't the case here (no proxies are being made for this class). Also if there is an interface you can make your classes `final` (which is also included in the not accepted but better answer in the question you linked).

Comment: It solved for me. I reproduced example. With `final` keyword tests didn't pass. After removing it tests passed successfully.

Comment: You cannot reproduce it because there is too little code in this question. So you created something similar but not the same, hence no reproduction.

Comment: @M.Deinum  `@Repository` annotation is the issue. `Spring` will try to create proxie for this class to wrap all `SQLException`'s to its own exceptions

Comment: Doh. Missed the `@Repository` annotation, that somehow internally translated to `@Component` :(. However, I would expect a different exception to occur.

Comment: @vszholobov I cannot remove the downvote (to long ago), but the answer is also a bit thin. You might want to add an explanation for the `@Repository` annotation and post processor. (That would allow me also to remove the down-vote).

Comment: Should i quote answers which I link in my own? I think second answer from link would be a good fit, but i didn't add it to mine since there is a link to it.