# How does spring create proxy for a final class?

Tags: java, spring, cglib

Maybe I have some outdated knowledge but it is the same as described here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2657465/2674303

But now I noticed that this example works without any exceptions:

```
@Service
@EnableScheduling
public final class MyService {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("MyService started");
    }
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay= 1000)
    public void scheduleCall() {
        System.out.println("scheduleCall");    
 
  }
}
```

Could you pease provide how does it work ?

Comment: It uses Magic!  And Lies!  As far as I know, modern frameworks are able to use byte code rewriting to change the `final` class as it's loaded (i.e., during class load).  Thus you get a "different" class without having to extend it.  But this technology moves pretty fast and there's always more than one way to do it, so it could be any technique really.

Comment: @markspace
 We should find a MythBuster for that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) annotation does not require proxy creation. The mechanism is different. After bean initialization Spring called post-processor [ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html). Post processor searches for all methods annotated with `@Scheduled` and registers them to [TaskScheduller](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/TaskScheduler.html) for execution. Method execution will be performed via reflection.

See [ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/ba0473e88536a2f0e5570ccc34f8ba254523f92b/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L354).

[@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html)

> Processing of @Scheduled annotations is performed by registering a
> ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor. This can be done manually or,
> more conveniently, through the task:annotation-driven/ XML element
> or @EnableScheduling annotation.

[ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html)

> Bean post-processor that registers methods annotated with @Scheduled
> to be invoked by a TaskScheduler according to the "fixedRate",
> "fixedDelay", or "cron" expression provided via the annotation. This
> post-processor is automatically registered by Spring's
> task:annotation-driven XML element, and also by the
> @EnableScheduling annotation.
>
> Autodetects any SchedulingConfigurer instances in the container,
> allowing for customization of the scheduler to be used or for
> fine-grained control over task registration (e.g. registration of
> Trigger tasks). See the @EnableScheduling javadocs for complete usage
> details.

[@PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html?is-external=true) also implemented via post-processor [InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) when dependency injection performed for bean, method which marked `@PostConstruct` will be executed thru reflection without proxy.

See [InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/ba0473e88536a2f0e5570ccc34f8ba254523f92b/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java#L358)

**Summary:**

In your example, Spring will create bean without proxy.

In case you will add a proxy-specific annotation, for example, `@Transactional` you will get an exception that proxy can not be created due to final class `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class com.test.services.MyService`

```java
@Service
@EnableScheduling
public final class MyService {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("MyService started");
    }
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay= 1000)
    @Transactional
    public void scheduleCall() {
        System.out.println("scheduleCall");

    }
}
```

But the current problem you also can solve to force use `JDK dynamic proxy`. We need to create an interface for class and set property `spring.aop.proxy-target-class = false` according to [Proxying mechanisms](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html)